# <Input /> and <Textarea /> are not aligned in native-base, React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I want to put oneline input and multiline input in form using native-base, but they are not correctly aligned to vertical line. Is there anything I am missing or should they not used together? Thank you.

part of package.json

```
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "native-base": "2.13.8",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
```

My code

```js
      <Content padder>
        <Form>
          <Item regular floatingLabel>
            <Label style={{paddingTop: 2}}>Label</Label>
            <Input onChangeText={url => setUrl(url)}/>
          </Item>
          <Textarea
            rowSpan={5}
            onChangeText={content => setContent(content)}
            bordered
            placeholder="this is textarea"
          />
        </Form>
      </Content>
```

[image: screenshot of simulator]

========edited

I found an answer, just replacing floatingLabel with regular. However, placeholder are still not aligned.

```js
          <Item regular>
            <Label>URL</Label>
            <Input onChangeText={url => setUrl(url)}/>
          </Item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the padding at the style of your textarea.

`<Textarea style={{paddingLeft: over9000}} ... />`